# how I prove a valid recursion?

Tags: recursion

Determine whether is this a valid recursive definition of a function f from the set of nonnegative integers to the set of integers. If f is well defined (valid recursion), find a formula for f(n) when n  is a nonnegative integer and prove your formula is valid.

f(0) = 1, f(n) = -f(n-1) for n >= 1

This is extra work for a final exam tomorrow.

So I got f(0) = -f(0 - 1) = 1, so 1 = 1

So what are the next steps that I do next?

Comment: is that a question ?

Comment: yes, the question is: If f is a well defined (valid recursion), find a formula for f(n) when n is a nonegative integer and prove your formula is valid. 

Sorry for the bad question...

Comment: So what is the recursive definition you mention?

Comment: What is your recursive function in general? $f(n) = -f(n-1)$? Where did the $-f(-1) = 1$ come from? And what are you saying with 1 = 1? Do you mean $n_1 = 1$?

Comment: I just plugged in 0 for n. Was that wrong? Sorry, didn't realize the question was incomplete

Answer (score 2):

First, you should be able to make the (correct) guess that the function is $f(n) = (-1)^n$. Then, you prove this by induction. As you pointed out, the first step is to show the base case, that is that the claim holds for $n=0$.
$$
f(0) = (-1)^0 = 1
$$
Next, we suppose that the if claim holds for $n-1$, it must also hold for $n$. This is the induction step.
$$
f(n) = -f(n-1) = -1(-1)^{n-1} = (-1)^n
$$
By the principle of mathematical induction, $f(n) = (-1)^n$ for $n\geq 0$.

Comment: Ok, so why is the n an exponent now? Looks familiar, but please refresh my memory. Thanks

Comment: This is a **guess** you are making about the formula. The reasoning behind the guess varies, but you might want to try it out for the first couple of cases and then try to generalize your result. The idea behind the exponent is that $x^{n+1} = x\cdot x^{n}$